# Unicode characters in win32gui.AppendMenu render as question marks

Tags: python, winapi, unicode, menu, pywin32

I have a simple Python application that lives in system tray in Windows XP. The app is using pywin32 (Build 218) for its GUI and runs on Python 2.7.6. Everything was smooth until I tried to create a menu item with Unicode value:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import win32gui

...

menu = win32gui.CreatePopupMenu()
win32gui.AppendMenu(menu, win32con.MF_STRING, 1, u'Выход')
```

This menu item renders as five question marks ('?????') while ascii strings work just fine.

If I change the string literal definition for Python 3 and run it on Python 3.3.3, the menu item text displays correctly:

```
win32gui.AppendMenu(menu, win32con.MF_STRING, 1, 'Выход')
```

Renders as 'Выход'.

I have to stick with Python 2 as some of the modules the app is using are not compatible with 3.x.x.

Similar issues ([#1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4433542/318359), [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15983526/318359)) on SO with C WinAPI seem to be resolved by defining UNICODE and using L"" string literals. But I don't know how to accomplish this with pywin32. Using utf-16le encoding for the string doesn't help.

Comment: Shot in the dark: try with `win32gui.AppendMenuW`

Comment: @manuell Yeah, if only function like this existed in `win32gui`: `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'AppendMenuW'`

Comment: Then, you may use ctypes and call `ctypes.windll.User32.AppendMenuW`

Comment: It works! Thank you, @manuell. Could you please post it as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ctypes` allows to call native Win32 APIs.

Use `ctypes.windll.User32.AppendMenuW`

Comment: Can you give an example. Above function do not accept structure from "win32gui_struct.PackMENUITEMINFO" with error "ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 4: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 4"

Comment: @Durgaprasad Soory, I can't understand your question. The parameter 4 is either an unicode string, a bitmap handle, or an arbitrary 32 bits value. It depends on bits in the parameter 2. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647616

Comment: Got the answer. addressof(Hmenu01Info) will be 4th parameter. Another question is what is difference between MENUITEMINFO and MENUITEMINFOW. Second one is recomanded for InsertMenuItemW.

Comment: @Durgaprasad See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7424383/what-is-the-difference-between-the-a-and-w-functions-in-the-win32-api